# iOS Tapku library calendar is black on some devices (TKCalendarMonthTableViewController)

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, tapku

I'm using the Tapku library to show a calendar of events, it's showing correctly on my device (iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1.3), but on some other devices or the simulator, the calendar is black (check the screenshots)

[image: this is correct]

[image: this is incorrect]

The calendar is an object of TKCalendarMonthTableViewController

Any idea why it's not showing correctly everywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found it, the TapkuLibrary.bundle file was missing in the xcode project, just added it and it works fine.